# Quick Print HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I want to send/print the canvas image directly to the default printer. That means a quick printing.

Anyone can give a hint.

Javascript or jQuery.

Comment: What do you have problems with? Printing the image or getting it from the canvas? Or both? Please be more specific. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: toDataURL(), give us the image data from canvas. I want to send it directly to the printer.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I have searched alot and found a solution which works perfectly :)
Used **onclick** event

```
function printCanvas()  
{  
    var dataUrl = document.getElementById('anycanvas').toDataURL(); //attempt to save base64 string to server using this var  
    var windowContent = '<!DOCTYPE html>';
    windowContent += '<html>'
    windowContent += '<head><title>Print canvas</title></head>';
    windowContent += '<body>'
    windowContent += '<img src="' + dataUrl + '">';
    windowContent += '</body>';
    windowContent += '</html>';
    var printWin = window.open('','','width=340,height=260');
    printWin.document.open();
    printWin.document.write(windowContent);
    printWin.document.close();
    printWin.focus();
    printWin.print();
    printWin.close();
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work for me. It gives me a print dialog box rather then silently printing to the default printer

Comment: @PreyashDesai If I remember correctly, when printing using javascript the print dialog will always show before printing to prompt the user.

Comment: very interesting! but for my code when it gets to printWin.document.open(); I get this error:
cannot read property 'open' of undefined.
printWin.document is undefined

Comment: This is what I need, but beware!  My page has a very slow-loading image. `printWin.print()` can be invoked _before_ the page has loaded.
Better to add a little javascript in the `head` of the created page: `window.onload = function () { window.print(); window.close();}` and drop the last two statements in this example.

Comment: this solution does not work. opens quickly a popup and that's all.

Answer (score 26):

I found that the first time I printed, the canvas was blank.  I added an event listener to wait until the image/document is loaded.  Now the canvas is ready to print each time.  Here's the code which is working for me:

```
const dataUrl = document.getElementById('the-pdf-canvas').toDataURL(); 

let windowContent = '<!DOCTYPE html>';
windowContent += '<html>';
windowContent += '<head><title>Print canvas</title></head>';
windowContent += '<body>';
windowContent += '<img src="' + dataUrl + '">';
windowContent += '</body>';
windowContent += '</html>';

const printWin = window.open('', '', 'width=' + screen.availWidth + ',height=' + screen.availHeight);
printWin.document.open();
printWin.document.write(windowContent); 

printWin.document.addEventListener('load', function() {
    printWin.focus();
    printWin.print();
    printWin.document.close();
    printWin.close();            
}, true);
```

Comment: Nothing happens for me. The print dialog never opens. I tried tu put a breakpoint inside the load listener but it won't reach it.

Comment: @Elizandro-SparcBR try closing the window first and then print. Also remove the close  printWin.close(); Hope it helps.

Answer (score 7):

Use [printJS](https://printjs.crabbly.com/) and this one liner:

```
printJS({printable: document.querySelector("#your-canvas").toDataURL(), type: 'image', imageStyle: 'width:100%'});
```

Comment: Brilliant. It costed me just 3 lines. First for script import, second for style import with CDN and then the third one liner is within the answer. Great job. I tried so many answers here and there without any luck, spent about 4 hours to do some more customised tasks on this  topic but finally got the right answer. 
Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Updated @Martin's answer.

```
let windowContent = '<!DOCTYPE html>';
windowContent += '<html>';
windowContent += '<head><title>Print canvas</title></head>';
windowContent += '<body>';
windowContent += '<img src="' + dataURL + '">';
windowContent += '</body>';
windowContent += '</html>';

const printWin = window.open('', '', 'width=' + screen.availWidth + ',height=' + screen.availHeight);
printWin.document.open();
printWin.document.write(windowContent);

printWin.document.addEventListener('load', function () {
  printWin.focus();
  printWin.document.close();
  printWin.print();
}, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I quickly googled this and found this [link](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1903884&seqNum=9).  It gives a breif tutorial on how to do it, but essentially you get a reference url with: `toDataURL()` and then create an img with the same size, assigning its src to the url.

It gives a better step by step of what to do in your html and css, so just look at the [link](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1903884&seqNum=9) if you don't understand what i said.

Note: I assumed you were having trouble interacting with the canvas to print, but if instead you are having trouble with the printer driver then this is probably of no use to you.

Comment: toDataURL(), give us the image data from canvas. I want to send it directly to the printer.

Comment: i know, but you can temporarily create an image and then print that image. and then you can remove the image.  i dont know of any way to directly do this with the canvas so it's a bit of a work around

Comment: ok, thats a work around. but how do we silently save the image to a hard disk location? and how to send that image to printer? couple of code lines will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As answer by Martin Macauley but for mobile chrome it doesn't work properly because you only have to close the doc inside a 'setTimeout' func

```
function PrintPDFFunc(ID){
const dataUrl = document.getElementById(ID).toDataURL();
let windowContent = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Print</title></head><body><img src="' + dataUrl + '"></body></html>';
const printWin = window.open("", "", "width=" + screen.availWidth + ",height=" + screen.availHeight);
printWin.document.open();
printWin.document.write(windowContent);
printWin.document.addEventListener("load",function(){
    printWin.focus();
    printWin.print();
    setTimeout(function(){
        printWin.document.close();
        printWin.close();
    },901);
},true);
```

}