# How to print html canvas onto paper

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have created a HTML based webpage consisting of a `form`, some `texts` and a `canvas`. I am trying to print this page that includes the canvas on a piece of paper. But the problem is - the canvas can't be printed. I also used `toDataURL()` method to convert the `canvas` to an image before printing, but it  still didn't work. Could anyone give me some clues?

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 100);
var img = c.toDataURL("image/png");
document.write('<img src="'+img+'"/>');

function printData(){
 var divToPrint=document.getElementById("printTable");
 newWin= window.open("");
 newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
 newWin.print();
 newWin.close();
}

$('#printButton').on('click',function(){
printData();
});
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<table id="printTable">
<button type="button" id="printButton" class="btn btn-info"> Print </i></button>
<tr><td>Data1 : </td><td >HTML</td></tr>
<tr><td>Data2 : </td><td >CSS</td></tr>
<tr><td>Image : </td><td >Wanna print the image here.</td></tr>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quick Print HTML5 Canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809971/quick-print-html5-canvas)

Comment: Here you use JS selector and Jquery selector. Have you include jquery ? Try to use only one of them.

Comment: Has anything been drawn on your canvas at the time you call toDataURL ?

Answer (score 0):

what you could do is try some of the other good answered solutions on other asked pages which is quite similar to what you are trying to archieve.

Try checking here:
[Capture HTML Canvas as gif/jpg/png/pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf)

Comment: ... and the modern browsers (Chrome, FF & Edge) all allow you to right-click-save-as the canvas to a desktop image. Then the user can right-click-print that image.