# Website using PrimeNG not printed entirely

Tags: javascript, html, angular, primeng

I have an web-based app running Angular 2 and PrimeNG. The application uses an accordion as main control and renders one large canvas inside one of the accordion tabs. The entire page is so large, that the user needs to scroll down horizontally.

The requirement is to have that entire page printed as PDF. My first try was `window.print()`, however then only one part of the page (starting from the top) is printed and the canvas is omitted using Chrome.

Any ideas how to convert the **entire** web page into PDF?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809971/quick-print-html5-canvas

Comment: At least I can help the user to print the canvas to PDF. Thanks for the hint!